# jQuery / JSON API Getting around the same origins policy with PHP proxy script

Tags: php, jquery, json, proxy, cross-domain-policy

I am trying to write a jQuery script that can read a JSON file from a server that I don't have access to. 
My two scripts are a PHP proxy script:

```
<?php 

$content=file_get_contents($_GET['http://fixyourstreet.ie/api?task=incidents&by=catname&name=Litter%20and%20Illegal%20Dumping']);
echo $content;
?>
```

And a jQuery script:

```
 <script>
$.getJSON( "proxy.php", function() {
  console.log( "success" );
});
 </script>
```

When I run this in chrome I get the following errors in the console:

```
>1 OPTIONS file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/json/proxy.php Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin. jquery-1.9.1.js:8526

>2 XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/json/proxy.php. Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

I don't understand why I still get a Control-Allow-Origin error even after I have made a PHP proxy script.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your rest service before returning response set a header parameter called `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` to `an address` or `public by setting *`.

Comment: header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *"); did the job! Thanks a million

Comment: Where exactly do you do this? Pardon my ignorance but "In your rest service before returning response set a header parameter called..." is ambiguous to me. I am using $.getJSON().

Comment: @rexbelia in the server side, where the rest service is written.

Answer (score 0):

file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/json/proxy.php - You obviously opened the file with jQuery from filesystem, which doesn't work with chrome, and possibly other browsers. And you need webserver to execute your proxy.php.

Solution: visit `http://localhost/json/` in your brwoser.